# Implicit self in Python

Tags: python

In Python, to reduce clutter, is there a way to "Declare" members/methods of a class as "self" or a workaround.

```
class range:
    #range_start # Declare as self
    #range_end   # Declare as self

    def __init__(self,my_range_start,my_range_end):
        range_start = my_range_start
        range_end   = my_range_end

    def print_range(self):
        print ("%x %x" % (range_start,range_end))
```

Comment: you can use self.range_start and self.range_end...is that what your question is?

Comment: I don't want to use self.

Comment: @Jean, there's nothing to do with it. It is how python works.

Comment: There isn’t, and it doesn’t really seem like there’s a good reason to, either. Lots of complexity to save very few characters (and that’s not even counting this proposed declaration, which defeats the purpose [?] of saving… something).

Comment: @minitech what OP wants to do is stupid, but it's not like there is no way to do it. You can try dynamically injecting self variables into globals by declaring a descriptor for a name in a class block and do the magic by having the class use a specific metaclass to prepare the globals before calling the `__get__` of methods. It's stupid and helps nothing, but it's not like it's impossible.

Comment: @OdraEncoded: But you can’t assign to globals implicitly anyway. The only ways I can think of to do this are by rewriting the method (grab AST, find matching assignments, modify, compile) or by ending it with some sort of `self.assign(locals())`.

Comment: @minitech Explain "Lots of complexity"
My incomplete(many more `self.` to be added) script is 22k big. I tried removing all `self.` from the script and it was 20k (10% reduction is file size after removing 192 occurrences) I thought the idea of programming is to let computer perform obvious inferences and let programmers worry about more important stuff. I disagree with this Python philosophy.. Or am I doing something wrong since there are too many `self.` in my code.

Comment: FWIW, it's perfectly fine to disagree with the "python philosophy". That doesn't make it incorrect (or correct for that matter). It's the way the language was designed and, like all languages, the design is not meant to please everyone.

Comment: @Jean: File size is not a particularly important metric. (If you’re not already, change those space indentations to tab and watch those bytes disappear! Remove comments and doubled newlines while you’re at it.) Anyway, if a “declare as self” line for each attribute at the top of the class would help you out, you either have too many of them or are referring to each one too many times. If it’s the latter (adding to a list or something), store it in a variable and then assign it to the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any straightforward way to do this. Also, if you did, you'd violate some rather deep set python conventions and your code would become much harder to read for other Python programmers. Too high a cost, in my opinion, to reduce visual clutter.

Comment: Sure..But give that choice to the programmer.

Comment: Not in Python. The language tends toward "One and preferably only one way to do it".  After working on a large perl code base for a few years, I've come to appreciate this. A set of language enforced rules in a large team makes the code much more readable and manageable for everyone.

Comment: Isn't this philosophy violated for `re.match` which does the same thing as `re.search(r'^...')` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not achieve what you ask for in the way that you want, the idea of implicit `self` has been discussed and discarded by the python community.

However, concerning your code example, you can reduce the amount of code:

```
class range(tuple):
    def print_range(self):
        print("%x %x" % self)
```

Still, that code is bad, because adding a `print_range()` function is the wrong approach (why is it called `print_range()` and not `print()`, btw?). Instead, provide implementations of `__str__()` and `__repr__()` to format the object.

Some more notes:

- There is a `namedtuple()` function that creates a type similar to a `tuple`, which you should perhaps take a look at.
- Calling the object `self` is a convention, you can name it anything you like. Others won't easily be able to read your code though.
- Concerning style, check out PEP 8. There is a bunch of conventions that you should adhere to, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Yep, PEP 8 covers that, it should be `Range`.

Comment: I think what he meant was about masking the keyword `range`.

Comment: `range` is not a keyword, and yes, I understood that part. One important point is that types should be `UpperCase` while functions like `range()` should be `lower_case`. Accidentally overwriting functions (`id` and `list` are classics there) could not have happened then. I believe that PEP 8 also talks about this issue.